# After installing a new hard drive, I get system freezes

Tags: hardware, freeze, crash

Just like the title,  not sure why.  I have unplugged the drive and all is well. No particularly unusual temp reports from my CPU or GPU, and last night it actually had the monitor off when it froze.

My first thought was that it might have something to do with my Nvidia driver, but that wouldn't explain why the problem ceased after unplugging the drive.

The drive itself is a Hitachi 3 TB, refurbished, with a reported MTBF of over 200 years, so it seems unlikely that it's faulty. My power supply is a 750 Bronze+, I have it delivering to an MSI motherboard with an FX-8300, a Seagate 1 TB, a Hitachi 2 TB, and if is plugged in, the new Hitachi 3 TB. My graphics card is a GTX 1660, relatively new,  and probably the most demanding thing on my system.

To be clear, when I say "freeze", I mean I get a still video image and total unresponsiveness to input. I have to hold the power button to turn it off; I cannot kill the X server or control+alt+F1, or even Control+alt+delete.

The drive mounted and formatted to Ext4 fine.  I use this machine for animation and video, and kind of need that extra storage space (frame sequences can easily reach half a gigabyte). I use Mint 19.2 right now.. What on Earth is most likely to be my problem? Do I need a better PSU? Could it be a cooling issue? The drive is sitting unplugged until I can figure this out.

**Addendum:** It's been suggested that I look at journalctl to find out what went wrong. I wasn't familiar with journalctl, but it seems super-useful in cases like this. Here's the final output before a clear freeze last night, the next update being around 7:45 after hard rebooting:

```
Jul 20 23:09:01 Selkie CRON[17923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 20 23:09:01 Selkie CRON[17924]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 23:09:01 Selkie CRON[17923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 20 23:09:25 Selkie systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jul 20 23:09:26 Selkie systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Jul 20 23:10:55 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device/start timed out.
Jul 20 23:10:55 Selkie systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device.
Jul 20 23:10:55 Selkie systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/1b038e00-c9ee-433c-97bf-64c06e0344d7.
Jul 20 23:10:55 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 20 23:10:55 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 20 23:12:22 Selkie wpa_supplicant[1680]: wlx7cdd90822d51: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 58:8b:f3:ad:00:49 [GTK=TKIP]
Jul 20 23:17:01 Selkie CRON[18223]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 20 23:17:01 Selkie CRON[18224]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 20 23:17:01 Selkie CRON[18223]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 20 23:22:33 Selkie ntpd[2259]: 103.126.53.123 local addr 192.168.0.2 -> <null>
Jul 20 23:25:28 Selkie smartd[1560]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 5 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Jul 20 23:25:28 Selkie smartd[1560]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 5 Offline uncorrectable sectors
Jul 20 23:25:28 Selkie smartd[1560]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 102 to 113
Jul 20 23:25:28 Selkie smartd[1560]: Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered changed from 34 to 41
Jul 20 23:39:01 Selkie CRON[18910]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 20 23:39:01 Selkie CRON[18911]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 20 23:39:01 Selkie CRON[18910]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 20 23:39:29 Selkie systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jul 20 23:39:30 Selkie systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Jul 20 23:40:59 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device/start timed out.
Jul 20 23:40:59 Selkie systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device.
Jul 20 23:40:59 Selkie systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/1b038e00-c9ee-433c-97bf-64c06e0344d7.
Jul 20 23:40:59 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jul 20 23:40:59 Selkie systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1b038e00\x2dc9ee\x2d433c\x2d97bf\x2d64c06e0344d7.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 20 23:42:20 Selkie wpa_supplicant[1680]: wlx7cdd90822d51: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 58:8b:f3:ad:00:49 [GTK=TKIP]
```

This was before I unplugged the new 3 TB storage drive, so it was connected at the time.

There's a good chance that the five failing sectors are on the Seagate, but I suppose I can't be sure. In any case it's complaining about sdd here, Seagate is now sdc, and I'm aware of the five dead sectors on it. The Hitachi drive was sold to me by Amazon with the promise of "zero bad blocks" and has been recently formatted. (The idea is to eventually replace the Seagate 1TB, but first I've got to successfully copy the data off of there!)

Unfortunately most of my programming skill is with multimedia development, so I must, humbly, admit that a lot of this is not fully understood by me. Hopefully someone can help me make sense of it and identify the problem and what I need to fix?

Comment: No error log on journalctl? If yes probably PSU, but you also need to monitor the drive temp into file, so you could see if it's thermal issue or not. But I never seen thermal issue so bad for HDD.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto Neither have I. I admit my case could use a dusting but it isn't that bad. I'll check those files and see if I can find anything interesting.

Comment: Sometime last night I got a number of dependency fails on a dev-disk-by-uuid. I don't recognize it, but I wouldn't. After that the was a long pause until 7:45 when I rebooted. I'll see if I can get the actual slice up, this thing is still acting fishy, just not in the same way.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto I added the relevant chunk of journalctl. Perhaps it will make sense to you what's going on? It might be a PSU. I'd be a little sore about it if I grabbed an 850W Gold+ and found out that it was something else, but at least that would be progress. Thank you for your prompt interest in this!

Comment: It's looking like this might be a possibility with bad sectors on the drive, given that it's on a SATA3 controller and my desktop computer only has one. I'm going to plug it back in, unmount it, and see about verifying the "zero bad blocks" promise as tangibly correct. My machine may be repeatedly attempting to read a failed sector on the hardware level, by its design, and locking things up below even the kernel. If it is bad, I may RMA the whole thing and get a new one.

Comment: I think one is try to boot liveCD/USB, then test it with GParted GUI or other tools. If it still problematic then go with RMA. I hope your data are safe.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto Thanks, I've backed everything critical up to the cloud so the damage should be minimal. It's my goal in the next couple of months to build a new studio machine anyway, so I should have plenty of opportunity to test that drive out.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few days with the new Hitachi unplugged entirely, I got the same system crash. It might involve the old Seagate, or more likely,  I'm dealing with [The Summertime System Gremlin](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/does-summer-weather-increase-heat-in-a-computer.3323313/). Turns out it's 85 F, or roughly 30 C, in here, and this thing is air cooled. (Only now do I realize the benefit of liquid cooling...)

It doesn't help that in spite of my regular maintenance and cleaning of this machine, it's got a 2012 CPU in it. (FX-8300). It may be time to build a new one from the ground up and write it off in my taxes.

Anyone who encounters this in the future,  from say a Google search, should identify the operating temperature of their machine and check the cleanliness of their fans and heat sinks. Note that `k10temp` on AMD does not report the physical temperature, it's likely to be high or low compared to the actual core; they models their processors to return a unit that is not degrees and relates to triggering fan speed.

Or wait until September and don't do anything irreplaceable with it. Your call.